# How to set js function scroll let it don't exceed parent‘s bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrolltop

The html, js, css example is https://jsfiddle.net/t9mfmaa3/5/.

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(function() {

  var $sidebar = $("#e"),
    $window = $(window),
    $offset = $sidebar.offset(),
    $topPadding = 15;

  $window.scroll(function() {

    if ($window.scrollTop() > $offset.top) {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - $offset.top + $topPadding
      });
    } else {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
#c {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2400px
}
#e {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 600px
}
#b {
  height: 2400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="a">
      <div id="b" class="column col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
        <div id="e" class="">
          blue
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="c" class="center_column col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
        red
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to make blue block not exceed yellow block which means the blue one always in yellow block. My idea is to set code to detect block yellow and block blue. But I didn't success. Anybody has any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using bootstrap, you may as well use their affix javascript.

[getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Here is an example:

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/t9mfmaa3/6/)

```
$(function() {

  var $sidebar = $("#e"),
    $body = $('body'),
    $parent = $('#b'),
    topPadding = 15,
        offset=$sidebar.offset();
    $sidebar.affix({
        offset: {
        top: function() {
        return $parent.offset().top - topPadding;
      },
      bottom: function() {
        return $(document.body).height() - ($parent.offset().top + $parent.outerHeight());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You might notice it act a little weird and jumpy near the end, but that should go away when using it on a real site (instead of inside an iframe)

Comment: Any idea why the width of the blue is changed?

Comment: Since the element's width isn't set it defaults to auto. The div is a block element so auto will fill up the full width of its container. When its affixed it gets position:fixed which removes it from its normal flow and makes the auto width size according to the content rather than the parent.